# Как при выводе списка первую букву нулевого элемента сделать заглавной?

Tags: python

например , у меня есть список

```
a = ["небо", "кроет", "буря"]
print(*a) # небо кроет буря
# а нужно: Небо кроет буря
```

как такое реализовать?

Comment: `print(a[0].capitalize(), *a[1:])`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов У меня чуть внятнее ИМХО. И пожалуйста ответы — в ответы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, а что?

```
a = ["небо", "кроет", "буря"]
print(' '.join(a).capitalize())
```

Comment: _а что?_ то что я не знал как это реализовать

Comment: @марат Надо подумать, что вы хотите сделать, разбив на шаги. Сначала список — в строку через пробел. Вспоминаем/гуглим, получаем: `' '.join(a)`. Теперь первую букву большую сделать. Вспоминаем/гуглим, получаем `' '.join(a).capitalize()`. Вот вам и все "реализовать". ;)

Answer (score 3):

@Михаил Муругов:

```
print(a[0].capitalize(), *a[1:])
```